# MongoDb aggregate format output

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose aggregate query:

```
Model.aggregate([
 { 
   $group: { 
     _id: "$user",
     total: {
       $sum: {
         $toDecimal: "$amount"
       }
     }
   } 
 }
])
```

which produces the following output:

```
[{
 "_id": "ABC",
 "total": {
   "$numberDecimal": "XYZ"
 }
}, ...]
```

Is there any way I could format it to produce slightly more readable results such as

```
[{
 "_id": "ABC",
 "total": "XYZ"
}, ...]
```

Comment: These are settings in your client application, there you should be able to change it.

Comment: The format you are seeing is _Extended Json_. The output for Number Decimal is distinguished from other MongoDB numeric types: int, long. float and double. Other tools may show the Number Decimal in a different format (for example, `mongo` shell has `NumberDecimal("12.55")`). You can also try transforming the result to `$toString` or ``$toDouble.